# How do I modify the short username in OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, user-accounts, user

I have modified my username from **Supreeth** to **Sagar R Kothari**. But I feel that it's not applied in most of the places where it's used.

1. The username **Supreeth** is found in each new project (e.g. project templates)
2. Each terminal window says `blrwks0157:~ Supreeth$`. It indicates that the username is still "Supreeth".

How do I modify the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate "user names".

> [image]

One is the *Full Name* displayed in *Users & Groups* preference pane, on the login screen, etc., e.g. *Daniel Beck*. This user name can actually contain spaces and other special characters.

The other is the internal *Account Name*, e.g. *danielbeck*. It needs to be alphanumeric only (so *there is absolutely no way of doing what you want to do!*). To change your short name, right-click your user account in *Users & Groups* preference pane, choose *Advanced Settings* and edit there. You should take the warning in that dialog serious though. You can break stuff by changing this.

---

You can always create a new user account and transfer your data over.